# Cannot restart VM instance in Google Cloud

Tags: virtual-machines, cloud, google

my website which I host on a VM in Google Cloud was unresponsive, so I stopped and tried to restart the VM. Stopping didn't work without a hard stop. Restarting doesn't work either.

"A g1-small VM instance is currently unavailable in the europe-north1-c zone. Alternatively, you can try your request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation."

I don't seem to be eligible to change the region for this VM, nor the hardware config.

Anyone any idea?

Would be much appreciated...

David